# Object type to store repeating calendar events with Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm creating a reminder-based type app like the simple alarm clock that ships with your iPhone.  I'm using Core Data and have an Alarm Entity that has a NSDate attribute for when the user schedules the time that the alarm should go off.  I want to also have the ability to schedule a recurring event like the Alarm clock.  I was wondering what a good way to do this would be?  I know that if the event repeats on certain events that follow NSCalendarUnit, you can just set the repeat interval.  But there isn't a repeat interval for only weekdays, or every other day or Mon, Wed, Fri, etc.

So far, the only solution I have is create another simple Entity that has string representations for Sun-Sat.  Each Alarm Entity would have a NSSet of these DaysOfTheWeekEntities.  Then when I want to schedule my UILocalNotification for the alarm, I would look up that alarm in the database which has its original creation date, calculate the next repeating alarms for the next month from the DaysOfTheWeek property.

I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One "smart" scheme would be to use that of the `cron` utility on unix systems.

From `man crontab`:

> The time and date fields are:
>
> ```
>     field      allowed values
>     -----      --------------
>     minute         0-59
>     hour       0-23
>     day of month   1-31
>     month      1-12 (or names, see below)
>     day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
>
>    A field may be an asterisk (*), which always stands for "first-last".
>
>    Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a
>    hyphen.    The specified range is inclusive.  For example,  8-11  for  an
>    "hours" entry specifies execution at hours 8, 9, 10 and 11.
>
>    Lists are allowed.  A list is a set of numbers (or ranges) separated by
>    commas.    Examples: "1,2,5,9", "0-4,8-12".
>
>    Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a    range
>    with  "<number>"    specifies  skips  of  the  number's value through the
>    range.  For example, "0-23/2" can be used in the hours field to specify
>    command    execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard
>    is "0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22").  Steps are also  permitted    after
>    an asterisk, so if you want to say "every two hours", just use "*/2".
> ```